# How to use 2 timepicker in single screen?

Tags: android, timepicker

I want to use Two `TimePicker` in single screen..

I tried but the problem is when i select one `timepicker` it will automatic generate the same time in another textview.

here **MainActivity.java**

```
       package com.example.sachin.timepicker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends  Activity {

    private TextView tvDisplayTime, tvDisplayTime1;
    private TimePicker timePicker1;
    private Button btnChangeTime, btnChangeTime1;

    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setCurrentTimeOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    // display current time
    public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {

        tvDisplayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        tvDisplayTime1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime1);
        //  timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // set current time into textview
        tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(minute)));
        tvDisplayTime1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(minute)));
        // set current time into timepicker
        //timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
        //timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime);
        btnChangeTime1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime1);

        btnChangeTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });


        btnChangeTime1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                // set time picker as current time
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                        false);

        }
        return null;
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                              int selectedMinute) {
            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;

            // set current time into textview
            tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                    .append(":").append(pad(minute)));
            tvDisplayTime1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                    .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

            // set current time into timepicker
         //   timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour);
           // timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute);

        }
    };

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: off course it's happening because you whenever you set time from the dialog it goes to both TextView `tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                    .append(":").append(pad(minute)));
            tvDisplayTime1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                    .append(":").append(pad(minute)));`

Comment: So now how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track which time button is clicked `isTimePickerFromClicked=True`
then in your `from` button is clicked set this flag to `False`.

Before you `setText` check if `isTimePickerFromClicked` is either `True or False` and `setText` accordingly

Update 1: Your code

```
public class MainActivity extends  Activity {


    boolean isFromClicked = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setCurrentTimeOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    // display current time
    public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {

        tvDisplayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        tvDisplayTime1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime1);
        //  timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // set current time into textview
        tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(minute)));
        tvDisplayTime1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(minute)));

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime);
        btnChangeTime1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTime1);

        btnChangeTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                isFromClicked = false;

            }

        });


        btnChangeTime1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                isFromClicked = true;

            }

        });

    }



    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                              int selectedMinute) {
            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;

                if ( isDateToSelected )
                    tvDisplayTime1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                    .append(":").append(pad(minute)));
                else
                    tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                    .append(":").append(pad(minute)));
        }
    };

}
```

Note: removed some code to reduce length.

Comment: @Murtuza I am new in this so can you please explain with some code?

Comment: oh thank you so much its working allright.. but what's the use of `isDateSelected`? instead i write `isFromClicked`

Comment: where is `isDateSelected` ?

Comment: private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener in if condition isDatetoSelected

Comment: apart from this how can i use 12 hour format on it?